# Solve $\int \frac{1}{x^2 \log{x}}\,dx$

Tags: integration

I have been trying to integrate this function, to no avail 
$$
\int\frac{1}{x^2\log{x}}\,dx
$$

Substituting $\log{x}=t$ doesn't improve things. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered $x=e^u$?

Comment: It is $Ei(-\log x)$ which has no closed form

Comment: @user170231`that is the substitution that Lodovico already used

Comment: @Ludovico Are you sure you copied the problem right? Just asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $Ei(-\log x)$ which has no closed form

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html